# Why can't we solve the consensus problem by just enforcing a new leader?

Tags: distributed-computing, theory, distributed-system, consensus, robustness

I am going through this lecture series by Martin Kleppman.
In [this](https://youtu.be/rN6ma561tak?list=PLeKd45zvjcDFUEv_ohr_HdUFe97RItdiB&t=82) video at around 1:25, he says you can manually configure the distributed nodes to chose a leader.

If that's the case can't we just automate the process by having a different process running that just checks for the health of the leader and chooses a new leader after the leader's failure or network partition.

Why is this problem actually so hard? Why can't we solve the consensus problem by enforcing a new leader without the nodes having to actually come to an agreement What am I missing?

Comment: For a second there I was going to mark as off topic because it’s about politics.  However, I do think this is best suited for the computer science stack exchange and not stack overflow. https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Haha. Okay I'll move it stackexchange

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have an active leader and a passive one. The passive one listens for active's heartbeat. When the heartbeat is not heard, the passive one switches to active mode and, maybe, tell everyone - "I am the leader...".

The problem is that just because the passive one hears no heartbeat, it does not mean that the true leader is off - maybe there is a network issue in between these two boxes?

Another option - the leader may get offline for a short period of time - enough for the passive one to detect; but later, the original leader comes back online - now there are two leaders.

The general problem to resolve here is how to build a failure detector. It is tricky. In the last example, the old leader comes back, thinks it is the leader; but that is not true.

Comment: +1 & another, by no means less important, is a distributed-system self-protection against spurious storms of consensus-seeking. adding some type of cost for leader to take place in spawning a new wave of consensus seeking is one such direction. Ms. Margaret HAMILTON's care, taken on blocking-prevention / timed conflict-resolution has saved Appolo 11 Moon landing - a lot to learn from ... *Anyway - **Stay well & stay tuned** & actively contributing to this great Community of Knowledge*